# Subdomain Redirection

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain

I have one of those fancy domains that when you include the subdomain spell out a whole word.

For example: g.oog.le

I'm having a heck of a time getting the redirects to work properly.

I want http://www.oog.le and http://oog.le requests to redirect to http://g.oog.le

Can I accomplish this with DNS records? Or do I need to edit the Apache config for the site? Or .htaccess? I've tried cname, .htacess and nothing is working...

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use `CNAME` records to point out to the servers you intended to reach. But, DNS operation happens under the hood, and browser is abstracted from a DNS lookup. So browser keeps the hostname you entered in `HOST` HTTP header field, which is potentially considered as invalid by orginal servers. HTTP redirects is a clever option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got it working perfectly with htaccess.